# Show an owned window without bringing to front

Tags: c#, wpf

A window without an owner is shown from a main window. The main window then shows a window it owns. The owned window brings itself and the main window to the front.

I would like the owned window and the main window to stay behind the window without an owner. Setting the property ShowActivated to false on the owned window does not prevent the windows from bringing themselves to the front, but does prevent stealing focus.

Any ideas on how to get the owned window to stay behind the ownerless window when calling Show?

```
Window ownerlessWindow = new OwnerlessWindow();
ownerlessWindow.Show();

Thread.Sleep(1000);

Window child = new ChildWindow();
child.ShowActivated = false;
child.Owner = this;
child.Show();

// Bring the ownerless window to the front
ownerlessWindow.Topmost = true;
ownerlessWindow.Topmost = false;
ownerlessWindow.Focus();
```

In the test application, the above code does put the ownerless window back in the front without a visible change in the window order. In the production application, there is a quick, visible change in the window order.

Comment: Why don't you just have the main window, after it shows the child window, bring the ownerless window back to the front? It is (it seems) the window that is in charge, so if you have a specific window arrangement you want, it should be the window enforcing that (especially since you don't want top-most for the ownerless window). If that's not going to work for you, please explain precisely why. Make sure you provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're doing, and why the obvious approach doesn't work.

Comment: This has the desired effect, but the window change is visible when the main window puts the ownerless window back in front (by setting the Topmost property to true and then false immediately after the child/owned window is shown). The window change is visible in the production application but not in the test application, possibly because there is not as much content in the test application windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Window ownerlessWindow = new OwnerlessWindow();

// set the ownerless window topmost first
ownerlessWindow.Topmost = true;
ownerlessWindow.Show();

Thread.Sleep(1000);

Window child = new ChildWindow();
child.ShowActivated = false;
child.Owner = this;
child.Show();
```

Comment: This is a good answer because it fixes the ordering without showing the windows changing, but it also requires the ownerless window to set Topmost to false after calling child.Show. It is simple to do in the test code, but when the ownerless window and the child window are created and shown in separate classes, it is more complicated, and there may still be a simpler solution (maybe).